# How to make progressive web apps with Blazor Server Side?

Tags: c#, progressive-web-apps, blazor-server-side

I am using the Blazor Server Side a lot. I want to make it an installable progressive web app. There is a lot of examples that show how to make a PWA with Blazor Wasm, but they don't show how to make a PWA with Blazor Server Side.

Is there a way?

Comment: pwa : progressive web app

Answer (score 22):

I solved the problem myself in a simple way.
When creating a blazor wasm project, you can create a pwa project.
After creating the project, I copied the manifest.json file, service-worker.js, and service-worker.published.js files in it to the wwwroot of my existing blazoer serverside project.
And at the bottom of the host.cshtml file

navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');

I entered
pwa works normally, install it on my Android phone and access it through the desktop icon

Comment: This is realy intersting solution. Did you found any issues since then?

Comment: In my case, I created a new app using 'dotnet new blazorwasm -o MyNewProject --pwa' then I copied the files from the wwwroot folder into my Blazor Client application. the navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js') line is actually in the index.cshtml file of the blazor client app

Comment: As @YordanYanakiev said before, this is really interesting solution. It's the only way I found how to implement PWA support to Blazor server-side project. Thanks.

Comment: The way you solved this is not the proper way to do this. I would write the detailed answer if this question was accepting new answers. But head over to https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials.AspNetCore.ServiceWorker and give a try.

Comment: @MahmudulHasan why not a proper way?... there's no proper way... it's up to you. It only makes it easier to integrate it in ASP.NET Core project.

Comment: Nice documentation available here, which complements the accepted answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/progressive-web-app?view=aspnetcore-8.0